# Mongoose object :javascript map function not working on adding new keys

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to add a new key on the JSON array return from the mongoose query

```
  find({chatBotId:req.params.chatBotId}).
  populate('userPlan').
 .exec(function(err,result){

   result.map(function(e){           
      e.transactionObject =null
      e.taxAmount = 100;    
      return e;    
    });
})
```

I am adding a new key `taxAmount` but it does not appear the array, however, `transactionObject=null` works fine it's an existing key

Comment: you have written `.populate('userPlan')..exec(function(err,`

Comment: You have to return `e` from the map function. And map will not mutate the original array. You may need to assign it back to result

Comment: are those double dots in front of `exec` a typo? If not those could be a part of your problem

Comment: @RaR e is already returned its a typo

Comment: RaR suggests `result = result.map`, are you using `result` later?

Comment: @iambatman Since map won't mutate the original array, do like `result = result.map(...`

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to do `result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))` or do:

```
result = result.map(function (e) {
  e = e.toJSON(); // toJSON() here.
  e.transactionObject = null;
  e.taxAmount = 100;
  return e;
});
```

Or even better use `lean()` (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean):

```
Model.find().lean()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `lean()` to prevent mongoose to [hydrate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.hydrate) the document.
Also `map()` function gets and returns an array. So I think it's better to use `forEach()` for the results.

```js
results = Document.find({chatBotId:req.params.chatBotId})
 .populate('userPlan')
 .lean()
 .exec(function(err,results){
   results.forEach(function(e){           
      e.transactionObject = null
      e.taxAmount = 100
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [MDN's page on `Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (emphasis mine):

> The `map()` method creates a **new** array

Your code

```
result.map(function(e){           
  e.transactionObject =null
  e.taxAmount = 100;    
  return e;    
});
```

doesn't actually do anything.

If you want to use the output of the `.map` above you have to re-assign it:

```
arrayWithNewKeys = result.map(function (e) {
  e.transactionObject = null
  e.taxAmount = 100;
  return e;
});
```

---

If you are using `result` later, expecting it to have the new keys `transactionObject` and `taxAmount`, you can re-assign `result` without needing to change your later code:

```
result = result.map(function (e) {
  e.transactionObject = null
  e.taxAmount = 100;
  return e;
});
```

Comment: but the `result` is still missing the `taxAmount` key

Comment: @iambatman `result.taxAmount` is obviously undefined, you've not set it anywhere

Comment: then how can i add the new key

Comment: @iambatman i honestly have no idea what you mean. Please edit into your question an example input and expected output

Comment: `taxAmount` Key is not present the output json I am trying to  add it using `map` function